# How to protect an NTFS external drive to be use both in Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: windows, password, ntfs

I share data between my Ubuntu and my wife's Windows on an external NTFS disc.

Sometimes I need to carry the drive with me, but I'm afraid of losing it because it has sensitive and personal info.

I'm wondering whether there is an easy option to prevent access to the unit in case it is lost or stolen.

I've tried rohos and similar software, but I would prefer something seamlessly integrated on the OSes.

Is there any way to encrypt NTFS and made it accessible by both Ubuntu and Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it:
installing TrueCrypt to both computers.

saving all the files on the external disc to a temporary space in one of your computers.

preparing the external disc as an encrypted container

assuming beginner's tutorial is read:

http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/tutorial

if you are experienced one:
 start truecrypt (either in linux or in windows)

1. create volume
2. create **a volume within a partition drive**
3. standard truecrypt volume
4. select device
   and so on ...

if you are **NOT** experienced one:

1. create volume
2. create **an encrypted file container**
3. standard truecrypt volume
4. select file

and so on ...

hope to hear if there is any other way of doing it.